# Having issues making static fields (non-method, primitive) in an ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'd like to create a `BankAccount` class where a new instance tracks the checking and savings of a new instance. However, whenever someone creates a new instance, I'd like a static method that calls a static field tied solely to the `BankAccount` class where it keeps tracks of how many bank accounts are open (sort of like the behavior of a singleton). This is doable in c#/java but having a hard time recreating the intended behavior in Javascript.

I attempted this in ES5 as well but came up short, the closest thing I came to the behavior I was looking for using a function as a wrapper to encapsulate:

```
function BankAccountMaker() {
    var countOfAccounts = 0;
    function IncrementcountOfAccounts() {
        countOfAccounts += 1;
    }

    function BankAccount(c = 0) {
        this.checking = 0;
    }

    return {
        makeBankAccount: function (c) {
            IncrementcountOfAccounts();
            console.log(countOfAccounts)
            return new BankAccount(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, a few asks:

1. Could someone code up the ES6 equivalent of the above?
2. Also, is there a better way to do this in ES5 where I don't require a wrapper?
3. How come in ES5 we can set the prototype method to a primitive but that doesn't seem like we can do that with ES6 syntax? (I am using Node 6.1 and Babel fwiw)

Comment: "*static field tied solely to the BankAccount class where it keeps tracks of how many bank accounts are open*" - **Don't**. That's exactly why (global/static, mutable) singletons are bad. It leaks memory and is unmodular (untestable). Keep the track record in the method where you create the instances. Exactly like you did with your `BankAccountMaker`.

Comment: "*How come in ES5 we can set the prototype method to a primitive but that doesn't seem like we can do that with ES6 syntax?*" - Please ask a separate question for that, and provide example code for what you mean. Btw, methods are no primitives.

Comment: Improvements to your code: 1) inline `IncrementcountOfAccounts` 2) Put `BankAccount` outside of `BankAccountMaker`, it's not a closure that needs access to the count - this will avoid re-creating identical classes. Then to convert it to ES6, just make `BankAccount` a `class`.

Answer (score 2):

I've added an id to every bank account. So you can iterate through your created accounts. `incrementcountAccounts` is a bad idea, because you didn't know if a bank account really was created.

You can't do this: `BankAccount(c = 0)` parameters are not supported in ES5.

Some snippets:

```js
/**
 * Bank
 */
class Bank {
  constructor(name, id) {
    this.countOfAccounts = 0;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    
    console.log('--- ' + this.name + ' ---');
  }

  incrementcountOfAccounts() {
    this.countOfAccounts += 1;
  }
  
  addBankAccount(...data) {
    this.incrementcountOfAccounts();
    
    return new BankAccount(this.id, ...data);
  }
}

/**
 * BankAccount
 */
class BankAccount {
  /**
   * Constrctor
   * @param  {Number} bankId     
   * @param  {Number} [amount=0]   
   * @param  {Number} [checking=0]            
   */
  constructor(bankId, amount = 0, checking = 0) {
    if(!bankId) {
      throw Error('no bank id');
    }
    
    this.account = {
      bankId,
      checking, 
      amount
    };
  }
  
  /**
   * Get bank id
   * @return {number}
   */
  get bankId() {
    return this.account.bankId;
  }

  /**
   * Set amount
   * @param  {number} value
   * @return {number}       
   */
  set amount(value) {
    this.account.amount = value;
  }  

  /**
   * Get ammunt
   * @return {number}
   */
  get amount() {
    return this.account.amount;
  }

  /**
   * set checking
   * @param  {number} value
   * @return {number}     
   */
  set checking(value) {
    this.account.checking = value;
  }  

  /**
   * get checking
   * @return {number} 
   */
  get checking() {
    return this.account.checking;
  }
}

const FirstBank = new Bank('First Bank', 1);


const bankAccount1 = FirstBank.addBankAccount(300);
const bankAccount2 = FirstBank.addBankAccount(4000);


console.log('Account 1: ' + bankAccount1.amount + ' - ' + bankAccount1.checking + ' - ' + bankAccount1.bankId);
console.log('Account 2: ' + bankAccount2.amount + ' - ' + bankAccount1.checking + ' - ' + bankAccount1.bankId);


console.log('Accounts first Bank: ' + FirstBank.countOfAccounts);

const SecondBank = new Bank('Second Bank', 4);
const bankAccount3 = SecondBank.addBankAccount(0, 1);
console.log('Account 3: ' + bankAccount3.amount + ' - ' + bankAccount1.checking + ' - ' + bankAccount1.bankId);    
console.log('Accounts second Bank: ' + SecondBank.countOfAccounts);
```

**ES5:**

```js
var BankAccountMaker = function () {
  this.countOfAccounts = 0;
  
  this.IncrementcountOfAccounts = function () {
    this.countOfAccounts += 1;
  }
  
  this.BankAccount = function () {
    this.checking = 0;
  }
  
  this.makeBankAccount = function (c) {
    this.IncrementcountOfAccounts();

    return new this.BankAccount(c);
  }
}

const Bank = new BankAccountMaker();

console.log(Bank.makeBankAccount(3));
console.log(Bank.makeBankAccount(3));
console.log(Bank.makeBankAccount(3));
console.log(Bank.countOfAccounts);
```

**ES5 Prototype:**

```js
function BankAccountMaker() {
  this.countOfAccounts = 0;

}

BankAccountMaker.prototype.IncrementcountOfAccounts = function() {
  this.countOfAccounts += 1;
}

BankAccountMaker.prototype.BankAccount = function() {
  this.checking = 0;
}

BankAccountMaker.prototype.IncrementcountOfAccounts = function() {
  this.countOfAccounts += 1;
}

BankAccountMaker.prototype.makeBankAccount = function(c) {
  this.IncrementcountOfAccounts();
  console.log(this.countOfAccounts);
  
  return new this.BankAccount(c);
}

const Bank = new BankAccountMaker();

console.log(Bank.makeBankAccount(3));
console.log(Bank.makeBankAccount(3));
console.log(Bank.makeBankAccount(3));
console.log(Bank.countOfAccounts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write up. I think I failed to articulate in my original question well enough - what I was looking for was a static field behavior like you find in C#/Java. That said, based on your supplied answers as well as Bergi, it's just not a feature in the ES6 language.